# Альфа смешивание при помощи текстуры

Tags: c++, opengl, графика, текстура

Есть две текстуры, одна цветовая, другая прозрачности (для колец планеты)
Не понимаю, как в шейдере нужно сделать, чтоб в местах, где чёрный, цвет был прозрачен у цветовой
карты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю что-то такое

```
alphaColor= texture(alphaTexture, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb;
diffuseColor= texture(mainDiffuseTexture, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb + alphaColor;
```

Но результат такой..В таком случае чёрный цвет хоть и отсекается, оставляя белый, но цветовая карта не зависит от карты прозрачности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение** написал в ответе, вот результат)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, товарищ user7860670 был прав, спасибо)
Лично для себя в виде **решения** сделал такое:

```
vec4 alpha = texture(alphaTexture, fs_in.TexCoords);
vec4 ringColor = vec4(texture(mainDiffuseTexture, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb, (alpha.r + alpha.g + alpha.b) * 0.33333)
```

Последний параметр 0.33333 можно менять, как вам угодно, да и вообще формулу под себя подстраивать.
Не забудьте перед отрисовкой включить альфа-смешивание:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
_planetaryRing->Draw();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: эм, в альфа текстуре по идее должен быть только один канал, т.е. вместо `(alpha.r + alpha.g + alpha.b) * 0.33333` только `alpha.r`

Comment: Там нет каналов прозрачности, там просто цвета от белого к чёрному в разных оттенках, там где он темнее, прозрачность должна быть выше, соответственно, где полностью чёрное, там отсекается)
Скрин результата прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Если оставить один r, то намного темнее картинка получается, так что лучше все три задействовать на всякий случай)

Comment: А там кроме r ничего быть не должно. Зачем цвета от белого к черному?

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо включить альфа-смешивание на стадии растеризации

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

А потом выдавать цвет в шейдере как RGBA.

Comment: Как понять выдавать цвет в шейдере как RGBA? 
Имею в виду, как мне эти две текстуры использовать так, чтобы одна зависела от другой?

Comment: Надо возвращать float4, беря 3 компонента из цветной текстуры и 1 - из текстуры прозрачности.

Comment: Что-то типа:
float alphaColor= texture(alphaTexture, fs_in.TexCoords).a;

vec4 diffuseColor= vec4(texture(mainDiffuseTexture, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb, alphaColor);
?